# Why does the image i uploaded do not save in the database and in the folder i assigned it to?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, image, mysqli

i don't understand why the image i upload when i create news doesn't save both in my database and in the folder. there's no error either that's why i couldn't figure out what's wrong with my code.

here's my createNews.php

```
<form action="/cn/admin/post_news.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Title</label>
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control">
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                    </div>
             </div>
             <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Image:</label>
                        <input type="file" name="file" multiple accept='image/*' >
                            <p class="help-block"></p>
                    </div>
             </div>
            <div class="control-group form-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <label>Body:</label><br>
                            <textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="body" class="form-control" id="body" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
                         </div>
            </div>
                         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post News" style="float: right"/>

            </form>
```

and this is my post_news.php where the process happens.

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
include_once('db.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $title= stripslashes($title);
    $body= stripslashes($body);

    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
    $body = mysql_real_escape_string($body);

    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $destination = "/cn/news-images/";

    $new_size=$size/1024; // file size in KB

    // make file name in lower case
     $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
     // make file name in lower case

     $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "cn";
    $connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    if ($connection->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($loc,$destination.$final_file)) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO news (title, body, name, date, photo, type, size) VALUES('$title','$body','$name','$date','$final_file','$type','$new_size')";
        mysql_query($sql);
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your news has been posted!'); window.location.assign('home.php');</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO news (title, body, name, date, photo, type, size) VALUES('$title','$body','$name','$date','','', '0')";
        mysql_query($sql);
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Your news has been posted!'); window.location.assign('home.php');</script>";

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You're mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` which won't work.

Comment: the body and the title actually save, except for the image @Chay22

Comment: First thing, you should try to provide us with a minimum viable example. There are lots of lines in your code that are irrelevant to the problem you're facing, and they just make it harder for us to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Mysqli so Instead of using mysql_query($sql), use $connection->query($sql)

Comment: did what u said and it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

..and file saves to tmp dir. if you wants to place it in any place see

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

after
**$destination = "/cn/news-images/";**

about write to DB.....mb got it in post before...